# Is there a way I can type classical Japanese (文語) relatively easily?

Tags: discussion, kanji, ime

I was taking some notes for classical Japanese, but it's hard for my to type simple words because my IME (Microsoft's default Japanese IME on Windows 11) doesn't show the proper kanji for their classical readings.

For example, I was trying to type 据う{すう}, but すう doesn't give me 据 in my IME. I have to take a roundabout route: すえる -> 据える -> 据う. Is there a better way?

Comment: How about trying this IME? https://support.justsystems.com/faq/1032/app/servlet/qadoc?QID=028069

Comment: There seems to be a [free dictionary file](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA051930/index.htm), but you need to use the older IME (cf. [this instruction](https://app.erisfelix.com/system-dictionary-add-microsoft-ime-windows10/) )